# My sql IN function not working in jasper ireport

Tags: spring-mvc, jasper-reports

I am passing po no parameter ('Aerotech/ATA/05/12','ACSPL/PO-0333/2013-14','ACSPL/PO-0333/2013-14') in  jasper my sql query .single value is working fine but multiple value not working . please help.........

parameter name="po_no" class="java.lang.String"

select cus.project_customername,cus.project_customer_billaddress,
cus.line2_billaddress,cus.line3_billaddress,cus.project_customer_phoneno,
cus.project_customer_fax,cus.project_customer_email,cus.city,cus.project_customerstate1,
cus.project_customer_country,cus.project_customer_postcode from cus_comercial_invoice inn,
cus_comercial_invoice_reference inr,
customer_purchase_order po,
customer_quatotion cq,enquiry_master_item ey, cutomer_mater cus
where po.purchase_id IN ($P{po_no}) and po.Quotation_no=cq.Quotation_no and cq.EnqueryID=ey.Enquiry_id and ey.customer_id=cus.projet_customer_id
and inn.cus_invoice_idno=inr.invoice_idno and inr.quantity!=0 and inn.cus_invoice_idno=$P{quatation_cus_id}

Comment: Did you try the `$P!{}` syntax?

Comment: this syntax already have used .

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you need is:

```
$X{IN, <db_col_in_query>, <param_name>}
```

The parameter will be of type query.

It's in the iReport / Studio documentation